# How do I properly show/hide elements after an AJAX call using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

What I'm using now requires two clicks for each action:

- First click: logs nothing, does nothing
- Second: logs `doesn't exist`, element displays
- Third: `(2) exists`, element doesn't toggle
- Fourth: `(5) exists`, element toggles
- Fifth: `(9) exists`, element doesn't toggle
- Sixth: `(14) exists`, element toggles

What's causing this weird behavior?

---

```
# views/articles/description.js.erb
$(function() {
    return $("#link-<%= @article.id %>").on("click", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var description = '<p class="article__description"><%= j @article.description %></p>';

      if ($("#article-<%= @article.id %> .article__description").length) {
        console.log("exists");
        $("#article-<%= @article.id %> .article__description").toggle();
      } else {
        console.log("doesn't exist");
        $("#article-<%= @article.id %> .article__info").prepend(description);
      }
    });
});

# views/articles/_article.html.erb
<div id="article-<%= article.id %>">
  <div class="article__expand">
    <%= link_to "Show description", description_article_path(article), remote: true, id: "link-#{article.id}" %>
  </div>
  <div class="article__info"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the HTML output, first with the element then without.

```
<div id="article-5">
  <div class="article__expand">
    <a id="link-5" data-remote="true" href="articles/5/description">
      Show description
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="article__info">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="article-5">
  <div class="article__expand">
    <a id="link-5" data-remote="true" href="articles/5/description">
      Show description
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="article__info">
    <p class="article__description">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Disable turbo links and try again.

Comment: The increasing number of `click` calls means that somewhere you are appending more and more click event handlers to same element .

Comment: @MarsAtomic I already have it disabled

Comment: @NikolayErmakov You mean `$("#link-<%= @episode.id %>").on("click". . .` is setting multiple event handlers? Is there another way to check that?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Can you show the resulting html and javascript you have on your page? Or give a link to an online site?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov There's no other JS, but I put the output HTML in my post. Not much there unfortunately :/

Comment: Seems to work here - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/5t52f6zt/. I only removed `return` from `return $("#link-` - you don't need it there.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Interesting, it must be Rails specific then. I'm new to Rails so I'm probably just missing something obvious.

Comment: I see an `xhr` argument in your click handler. May it be that you are doing something with ajax multiple times and so append as many click handlers to the link?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov I just left in the parameters in case I needed them, but [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) ( `<%= j @article.description %>`) does the `xhr` heavy lifting AFAIK.

Comment: Shouldn't you place that script in `article.js.erb` instead of `description.js.erb`?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov I set it as a custom method, `description` in `ArticlesController` with `respond_to {|format| format.js}`. Then mapped it in my routes: `resources :articles { member { get "description", to: "articles#description" } }` I know it's not the normal way but it didn't make sense to me to have it be `article.js.erb` when it's not the entire article I'm rendering. I think I'm going to try using JSON and just parsing it with `$.ajax` or `$.get`, still learning about that though. :)

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't help

Comment: @NikolayErmakov No worries, I ended up using JSON and got it to work!